# C++ : How can I push values into a vector only if that value isn't stored in the vector already?

Tags: c++

If for example, I was just pushing 200 random numbers into a vector, how can I ensure that duplicates will not be pushed in?

Comment: You may need a `set data structure` to Guarantee this

Comment: What is the range of the random numbers?

Comment: Agreed, std::shuffle() may be the solution.

Comment: @drescherjm Why would you need to use shuffle?

Comment: As Frank AK commented, you can use set data structure or use a map with vector to hold whether the item has been already added or not.  Like  map<item, bool> .  Check the map and add the item into the vector

Comment: If the range of numbers is 1 to 200 then you would use shuffle like in the last example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Answer (score 1):

seems like a map could be a helpful structure instead of a Vector.
If you must stick to a Vector then you need to divide your task into two parts; duplication detection and then insertion.  Again, your could insert into a map and then read that out into the Vector.
In either case the problem is - intrinsically - two problems.  Good luck!

Comment: Use regular expression and you'll have three problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the vector already contains the value, if not the push new value, i.e.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it = find (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), newvalue);
if (it == myvector.end()) {
    // newvalue is not found
}
```

But this could be costly since `find` method would be checking every value inside myvector.
Instead using `set` or `map` data structure can be more efficient.

Comment: Combine this with an efficient insertion algorithm (for a sorted list) and a binary search (on search-retrieval) and you'll have a scale-able system :)

Answer (score 1):

If the random numbers are integer and within a relatively small range, you can try this:
You want N unique random numbers from M possible values whereby M >= N

1. create a container containing one of each of the unique random number
2. shuffle the container
3. take the first N from the container and insert to your vector

If M is much bigger than N (like between 0 and rand_max), then you should just check for repetition before insert and repeat until your container size reaches 200. If using vector is not mandatory, I will suggest using std::set instead since it ensures unique values by default.

Comment: [Fisher-Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) doesn't require extra space.

Comment: The shuffle does not need extra space, but creating the container for all possible values does need space. If your possible values are integers between 0 and RAND_MAX, then you are going to create a container with over 2 billions values for shuffling. Does this worth when all you need is just 200 random numbers? The shuffling method is good when N is relatively close to M and collision chance using repetition method is very high in such case.

Comment: What you present does require extra space: you have a vector of M elements (to select `N` firsts). linked algorithm is similar in idea, but only need vector of `N` elements (the result vector). But indeed, in both cases, you have to generate `M` random number for permutation.